# Material-ui Card component's shadows and bottom get clipped when within GridList

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a grid made of [material-ui Cards](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/) using the [Grid List](https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/) component. However, in my attempt of putting the card within it, the bottom and shadow gets clipped. I think this is a very simple css issue but I cannot see what's wrong. Here is the sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/intelligent-wave-3gbzz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=light

In this image you can see how the bottom of each card is clipped when stacked with other cards on different rows. However, If you modify the window size, the cards without another card directly below it will render the bottom properly. This nehaviour can be checked in the sandbox link.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine your cards in the developer tools, you will see that it does not have any breathing room and that it uses `box-shadow` properties.

[image]

The box-shadow is configured to have `2px` as its `offset-y`, so you will need some bottom margin

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  card: {
    maxWidth: 160,
    height: "100%",
    marginBottom: "2px" // or margin: "2px" so at least all sides are covered
  }
}));
```

[image: Edit Cards within gridList material-ui (forked)]

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: Please bro give him some more margins (not only bottom)

Comment: I'd have to agree @adirabargil. But OP did specifically mention bottom. I put comments on the code in my edit

Comment: Haha thanks a lot, that makes total sense. I will give these cards some more breathing room in the future :D